# Unable to edit page on Adobe Contribute

Tags: adobe-contribute

I was editing a webpage on Adobe Contribute on a PC. I then installed Contribute on a Mac and attempted to connect to the same FTP server and edit it through Contribute.

On the PC, I used an old e-mail and have since gotten a new one. On the Mac I attempted to use the new e-mail address to register and edit on Contribute and I am locked out of the page and get the error "You can't perform this operation on this page now because (username) is currently editing or reviewing it."

I've deleted the site information on the PC and trying to log in again and it didn't work. I tried to set my new e-mail (on the Mac) as the administrator of the site and that didn't work. I Googled it and found that you need to delete lock files in order to solve this sometimes but I can't locate the lock files on the PC (possibly because I deleted the site all together from that computer). Any other ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are facing problem with the page "http://www.yoursite.com/mypage.html", then in the Contribute browse to the lock file of the page "http://www.yoursite.com/mypage.html.lck", then choose File--> Actions--> Delete Page. This will delete the lock file of the page and you can edit the page.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can easily manage locked file using Adobe Contribute 6.5. Yes Adobe Contribute 6.5 is out. More on http://blogs.adobe.com/contribute/2012/08/adobe-unveils-contribute-6-5-with-html5-support.html